# Is it safe to compare numeric constant (e.g. -1L) with == operator?

Tags: java

is it safe to compare primitive numeric constants (typically status values -1, 0, 1 ...) with comparison operator(s) "==" (and <=, >= as well)? What is best syntax to do so? What about performance? Take acount java immutable object caching (-128...127)...
Please, do not answer: "always use .equals()". It is more complicated than that. And yeah it could end with ".equals()" but I would like to hear deeper analysis. Also, I know that such status values should be enumerated. But real life shows us that a lot of API use numbers. Thanks.

Typical case could be: a Non-primitive status came "public Long getStatus(){...}" and needs to be null-safe compared to some basic values (positive, zero, small status values ONE, TWO, ...).

`Long status = response.getStatus();
final static Long NON_PRIMITIVE = new Long(-1);
final static long PRIMITIVE = -1L;`

1. `if (-1 == status)`
2. `if (-1L == status)`
3. `if (null!= status && -1L == status)  // Explicit null check`
4. `if (status == -1)                    // Does it matter Left/Right in autoboxing?`
5. `if (new Long(-1) == status)`
6. `if (new Long(-1).equals(status))     // correct, but terrible to read`
7. `if (NON_PRIMITIVE.equals(status))    // hypercorrect, really the best?`
8. `if (status.equals(new Long(-1))      // not null save`
9. `if (PRIMITIVE == status)`
10. `if (NON_PRIMITIVE == status)         // Correct for cached values only (-128..127)`

QUESTION 1: 
is `if(-1L == status)` really safe? (ignoring `null`)

QUESTION 2: 
What is best syntax to compare it null safe?

Comment: It is always "safe" to compare numeric (and hence "primitive") values with `==`.  **Except** when comparing floating-point values, where `==` must be used with great care.  In fact, `.equals` will not work with primitive values.  However, a `Long` is not "primitive", even if set from a literal.

Comment: if(status != null && status == -1) { }

Comment: In something like if `(-1 == status)` (where `status` is `Long`), I *think* that `status` will be "unboxed" prior to the compare (vs building a `Long` for the `-1` literal), so the compare should be fine (for any numeric value).  But it is always best to use explicit unboxing if you are unsure or want to make function clear.

Answer (score 0):

> if(-1L == status) really safe? (ignoring null)

Yes. Java caches values from -128 to 127. `L` is just an indication that the number is `Long`.

Try:

```
System.out.println(1L == 1);
```

> What is best syntax to compare it null safe?

If I understood you correctly, shouldn't

```
if(something != null)
```

be enough?

Answer (score 0):

- Numbers 1, 2, 4, and 10 are equivalent; all four will break when `status` is `null`, because of auto-unboxing. It does not matter on what side the boxed value is: compiler will generate code to unbox it for comparison. It also does not matter if you use a literal or a variable for the primitive value.
- Number 3 is safe, assuming that `status` has been produced with `valueOf` or autoboxed (which is the same thing).
- Number 5 would work if you use `Long.valueOf` instead of `new`, *and* the `status` came from code that autoboxes or uses `valueOf`.
- Numbers 6 through 8 are correct, but lengthy
- Number 9 is the fastest choice, but not the safest one. It would break if `status` hasn't been autoboxed, but was prepared using `new` instead.

Overall, `NON_PRIMITIVE.equals(status)` would be the safest choice, because it would work even in situations when `status` has been constructed using `new`.